# Merging two sorted lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

i have been trying to debug this code that merges two sorted lists into one sorted list im coding this problem from **leetcode**

```
typedef struct{
   int val;
   struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;
 

ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1,ListNode* l2){
        ListNode* head=(l1!=NULL||l2!=NULL)?(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)):NULL;
        ListNode* temp=head;
        ListNode* temp1=l1;
        ListNode* temp2=l2;
        if(temp!=NULL){
        while(temp1!=NULL&&temp2!=NULL){
                temp->val=(temp1->val<=temp2->val)?temp1->val:temp2->val;
                temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp=temp->next;
                if(temp1->val<=temp2->val){
                        temp1=temp1->next;
                }else{
                        temp2=temp2->next;
                }
        }
        ListNode* temp3=(temp1!=NULL)?temp1:temp2;
        while(temp3!=NULL){
                temp->val=temp3->val;
                temp3=temp3->next;
                if(temp3!=NULL){
                        temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                }else{
                        temp->next=NULL;
                }
        }
        }
        return head;
}
```

the logic seems fine to me but if we take an example
lets say we pass these two lists in
`ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1,ListNode* l2)`
`l1->(1)->(3)->(4)->NULL`
`l2->(5)->(6)->(7)->NULL`
my result : `head->(1)->(3)->(4)->(7)->NULL`
what it should be : `head->(1)->(3)->(4)->(5)->(6)->(7)->NULL`

Comment: The second `while` loop should look exactly like the first `while` loop, except that you should always choose `temp3`, instead of deciding between `temp1` and `temp2`.

Comment: @user3386109 it cant look exactly the same because when im in the first loop temp can never be NULL because there always will be atleast one more ellement to be handeled in the second loop , also in the second loop im only using temp3 wich its declaration is outside of any loop so i dont get what you ment when you said "except that you should always choose temp3, instead of deciding between temp1 and temp2"

Comment: Is the function supposed to merge the actual lists, or should it create a new list, containing the sorted result, without altering the two originals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the second loop:

```
ListNode* temp3=(temp1!=NULL)?temp1:temp2;
while(temp3!=NULL){
    temp->val=temp3->val;
    temp3=temp3->next;
    if(temp3!=NULL){
        temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

        /* 1 */
        temp = temp->next;
    }else{
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
}
```

Mark 1: you create a new element for the list, but you don't actually use it! That's why all the information is getting placed in the same node, and your output shows only the last element of the second list. Putting `temp = temp->next;` solves the problem.

Edit: regarding your `struct` definition:

```
typedef struct{
   int val;
   struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;
```

It threw a whole lotta warnings here on my test code. Suggest changing to:

```
typedef struct listnode_t {
   int val;
   struct listnode_t *next;
} ListNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's merge your two while loops too!

- Iterate through both the lists
- If first List has NULL value then assign the second list's value and vice versa
- If both lists are not emtpy then check the value and assign the lowest value.
- While loop will if atleast one list item (iterator) is not empty and after the end of the loop assign null to the last Node's next.

```
ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1,ListNode* l2){
    ListNode* head=(l1!=NULL||l2!=NULL)?(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)):NULL;
    ListNode* temp=head;
    ListNode* temp1=l1;
    ListNode* temp2=l2;
    
    while(temp1!=NULL || temp2!=NULL){
        if (temp1==NULL){
            temp->val = temp2->val;
            temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        if(temp2==NULL){
            temp->val = temp1->val;
            temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        if (temp1->val<=temp2->val){
            temp->val = temp1->val;
            temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }else{
            temp->val = temp2->val;
            temp->next=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp1=temp2->next;
        }
        
    }
    if(temp==NULL){
       temp->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: no it doesnt, i appreciate it but i actually want to know whats wrong with my code im not searching for a new one

Comment: The `temp->next = NULL;` at the end of the function is problematic, since `temp` can be NULL at that point.

Comment: @prewky , sorry but can you please  include your full code so that I can check, compile and run ?